# generate jar files for uploading kotlin lib to bintray using gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, bintray

I have the following `build.grade` configuration

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'


    dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.21"
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7.3"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
}

bintray {
    user = 'ishankhare07'
    key = '<api_key>'
    pkg {
        version {
            name = 'v0.0.1'
        }
        repo = 'server'
        name = 'server'
        licenses = ['MIT']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/ishankhare07/kotlin-web-server'
    }

}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += "./"
}
```

When I run `gradle uploadBintray` everything works fine but my repo on bintray ends up being an empty repository with no files. How to fix this?

Also I've tried adding a `jar` task as follows

```
jar {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    from {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

When I run this task with `gradle jar` it runs successfully

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s    
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
```

But I guess I've to link this somehow to the `uploadBintray` task which i cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [the docs for the `com.jfrog.bintray` plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#step-7-define-artifacts-to-be-uploaded-to-bintray), one of the ways to point the plugin to the artifacts you want to publish is using the `maven-publish` plugin.

This can be done as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        publishToBintray(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java // or use 'artifact jar'
            artifact sourceJar // optional: adds the source JAR artifact
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    publications = ['publishToBintray'] // use the name of the publication above
}
```

Another way described in the page linked above is to use Gradle configurations.